# Distance between nose and mouth using opencv and python?

Tags: python, opencv3.0, face-recognition, dlib

Im tracking two point from my face in a web cam stream using opencv. Im currently doing dist.euclidean(a, b) but the distance change depending how far Im from the camera and this is not what I want, I want the distance to be the same not matter where I am. How can I solve this?

Comment: you have to compensate for the fact that (in pixels) the distance is increasing.

Comment: And how would I do that?

Comment: there's probably a dozen different ways to do it.  Do some research, try things out (by hand, maybe), and come back with more specific questions.

Answer (score 1):

You need to know the focal length of your webcam as well as the distance you are from the webcam, otherwise, you cannot know the absolute distance since a camera only measure angle.

Answer (score 0):

You have to calculate a ratio between your distance and a given distance taken as model. For example the distance between the eyes.

Coming to your question, to correctly estimate the real distance in the picture you should have something with a known length at the same distance from the camera. In this way you may be able to get the real measure doing a pseudo code like the following

```
fakeDistance = 5
realLengthOfKnownObject = 10
apparentLengthOfKnownObject = 8
ratio = realLengthOfKnownObject/apparentLengthOfKnownObject
realDistance = fakeDistance * ratio
```

Obvious this is really hard to obtain.

I found [this article](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/01/19/find-distance-camera-objectmarker-using-python-opencv/) that might help.
Good luck.